# Emacs claims I'm quoting a lambda, but I'm not

Tags: emacs, clojure, elisp, emacs24

I added this to my init.el in emacs:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook
  (lambda ()
    (kill-buffer "*scratch*")
    (ido-mode t)
    (global-visual-line-mode 1)))

(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
    (rainbow-delimiters-mode 1)))
```

Now emacs automatically turns the word `lambda` into the symbol *lambda* but I don't know if that is the issue. When I startup emacs, it reports:

`(lambda (line) ...) quoted with ' rather than with #'`

But I am not quoting the lambda. If I remove the above lines of code, the error goes away.

Why does it give me that error?

Comment: There is no `field` argument in the above `lambda`s. It must be another `lambda`.

Comment: @Tobias not sure it makes a difference but actually it uses the word "line" not "field" i've updated the question. i can't imagine it is any other lambda since if I take out the above, the error disappears and everything loads.

Comment: It does make no difference. Search the init file for `'(lambda` anyway. I have the impression that sometimes the byte-compiler is just too smart about what he has to re-compile and what not. The quoted lambda can be somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a bug in your code, but in some code provided with Emacs that is called by one of the functions you're calling. It is quite possibly [Emacs bug #11357](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=11357).

Your code is appropriate, except that as sds noted you're overcomplicating things with `emacs-startup-hook`. Most things can be done right when your `.emacs` is being loaded.

```
(ido-mode t)
(global-visual-line-mode 1)
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook
  (lambda ()
    (kill-buffer "*scratch*")))
```

The only reason I can think of to use `emacs-startup-hook` the way you did is if you frequently reload your `.emacs` *and* you frequently change `ido-mode` or `global-visual-line-mode` and don't want them to be reverted when you reload `.emacs`.

For alternate ways of getting more out of Emacs than killing `*scratch*`, see [Automatically closing the scratch buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662655/automatically-closing-the-scratch-buffer) and [Prevent unwanted buffers from opening](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19874/prevent-unwanted-buffers-from-opening).

Answer (score 1):

1. The `lambda` in the warning has a `line` argument; your hooks do not. Either you have a different quoted `lambda` in your init file, or this is a bug in the byte compiler.
2. There is no reason to quote lambdas at all; you are doing it right.
3. I don't think that you are using `emacs-startup-hook` the right way; just put `(ido-mode t)` and `(global-visual-line-mode 1)` in the init file as is.