# Emacs ElScreen only shows one tab

Tags: emacs

I have installed ElScreen using `list-packages`, and I have the below in the `init.el` file:

```
(require 'elscreen)
(elscreen-start)
```

but then when I open a file `file-a.txt`, it will only show me the current filename in tab bar. I open a another file `file-b.txt`, that the tab bar will only show one tab for `file-b.txt` - `file-a.txt` is not listed.

Is there any method of showing all open buffers - with the exception of `* Messages *` and `* scratch *`?

Comment: You are thinking of what `tabbar.el` offers, not `elscreen`.  The two libaries are not compatible absent substantial work to create a custom marriage of both libraries.  Here is a link to a thread that describes some options with `tabbar.el`:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/10081/2287  The library `elscreen` remembers window layouts, not open buffers.

Comment: With `elscreen` you have to ask to open a new tab with `elscreen-create`. See http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Elscreen for the commands and a discussion about some tweaks like to isolate buffers in their tab or per project.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking if there is a method to show all open buffers: here is a very easy one :D 
you see the "Buffer" menu ? Click on it and click on the line of dashes

```
-----------  <--- click here
buffer foo
*scratch*
```

We can detach the menu like this and have it floating around and staying always on top. You've got your answer !

Now my commentary on elscreen: with elscreen you have to ask to open a new tab with `elscreen-create`. See http://www.wikemacs.org/wiki/Elscreen for the commands and a discussion about some tweaks, like  isolating buffers in their tab or per project

Last notes:

If you never want the scratch buffer:
[Automatically closing the scratch buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662655/automatically-closing-the-scratch-buffer)

Comment: (1) I am using elscreen still but I understand the concept better - that tabs != buffers, tabs contain buffers.  Therefore I clone an elscreen and then select the right buffer. (2) I cannot detach the buffers menu - possibly because I use windows. Thanks

Comment: Exactly. The idea generally for emacs users is that we'll end up with too many buffers open so that it would be impossible and not handy to have the same number of tabs. So we have many ways to quickly change tabs or see the list (C-x left/right, ido-switch-buffer, key chords, ibuffer,…). And I like it. I don't like any more editors like Sublime or Eclipse that have tabs, it isn't handy, the UI gets quickly overloaded.